# How do I wire up an event handler with Dispatcher.Invoke?

Tags: wpf

I'm writing a WPF application using .NET 4.5. The application will display data from a serial port. At the moment, I want to update the content of a multi-line textbox using the serial port's DataReceived event.

When I run the application, the commented line below throws an "`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`" with "`{Parameter count mismatch}`" The inner exception is null.

The RxString variable (it's a class member) in the event handler gets the value from the serial port so data is flowing from the device through the serial port and into the event handler. I'm not sure how to debug this further. Based on the sample code I found for a winforms app, this seems correct.

```
private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textbox1.AppendText(RxString);
}

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    textbox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));  // *** Exception occurs here
}
```

The stacktrace:

```
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at WpfSerial.App.Main() in c:\Users\scott\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SerialStuff\WpfSerial\WpfSerial\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
textbox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
```

with this:

```
textbox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(DisplayText(RxString));
```

Alter DisplayText() to take a string parameter like this:

```
private void DisplayText(string rxString)
{
    textbox1.AppendText(rxString);
}
```

I don't think you need "DisplayText" to be an EventHandler, nor do you need "RxString" to be a global variable.